# Firebase DataSnapshot.getValue() is null

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener

I've been looking at the other errors here in SO, in regards to mine and still can't seem to get anywhere, since I keep getting the DataSnapshot.getValue() returning null...

First I get the db-ref:

```
    private DatabaseReference f_database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("maps_data");
```

Then in my OnCreate method inside my activity I've added a listener:

```
        f_database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){ <<<< Problem is here, value is null
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    double lati = 0;
                    // Get UsersLocationFavorites object and use the values to update the UI
                    UsersLocationFavorites userLocFav = snapshot.getValue(UsersLocationFavorites.class);

                    LatLng location = new LatLng(userLocFav.getFavoriteSpot().getLatitude(), userLocFav.getFavoriteSpot().getLongitude());
                    gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Old Marker"));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And looking inside my firebase database, I have the following:

[image: firebase_database_picture]

I've double checked spellings ("maps_data"), I've looked an many SO-problems here, where I can't find one that fits my problem.

Can anyone see, what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the databases provided by Firebase.

All the code you're showing is accessing Firebase Realtime Database.  But the screenshot is showing data in Firestore.  These are completely diffrent database products.  If you want to read data out of Firestore, you should be using the Firestore SDK instead.

Comment: oh... Ehm.. Do you possibly have an example? Or is it just switching somehow from firebase to firestore?

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on how to use Firestore, if that's what you're trying to do. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Comment: oh, I see - thank you!! I should delete my question, I guess?

Comment: There's no requirement.